# Оценка скорости сайта без учета скриптов "яндекс-метрики"

Tags: pagespeed-insights, яндекс-метрика, pagespeed

На данный момент пытаюсь повысить скорость загрузки главной страницы сайта, оценку изменений произвожу через Google PageSpeed и Performance в консоли Chrome. Но результаты сильно разнятся от теста к тесту - есть предположение, что в этом виноваты скрипты Яндекс метрики.

Так вот, есть ли какой-то способ не учитывать скрипты метрики в оценке скорости загрузки страницы? Фактическое отключение или отложенный запуск невозможен т.к. будет ущерб для аналитики.

Также буду благодарна любым рекомендациям по этой теме, ссылкам на полезные ресурсы и т.д.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Отключить и попробовать без неё?

Comment: @IgorR., я же написала
"Фактическое отключение или отложенный запуск невозможен т.к. будет ущерб для аналитики."

Comment: Отключите только для себя, по определенному условию.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать один из атрибутов async или defer = https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script